# do while didn't go to next line even though it should end

Tags: java, sockets, do-while

I'm recently on a socket project. When I'm debuging my code I found a problem but I can't find out why, below is my code

```
 // some code that open a socket connection and put inputstream into a BufferedReader called 'in'

 String input;
 input= (String)in.readLine();
do{

    System.out.println(input);

}while(input!=null);

out.close();
in.close();
Socket.close();
```

as you can see, the above code create an infinite loop, when I send a string from server side, it keeps println that string.

if I do it like below

```
 String input;

do{
    input= (String)in.readLine();
    System.out.println(input);

}while(input!=null);

out.close();
in.close();
Socket.close();
```

the problem solved , and it works great. every time I send a string from server site, it just print once. BUT it didn't exit the loop and go to next line to close the socket connection .

So here is my question. if I put it within the do while loop. should the loop end and go to next line then disconnect the connection?? can anyone explain why the do while loop just execute once and didn't go to the next line?

Best

Answer (score 1):

If `input= (String)in.readLine();` is in the do-while loop, when you read in `null`, it will print `null` and then exit the loop.  Then, `out.close();`,`in.close();`, and `Socket.close();` will execute.

Comment: thanks for you help man.  there were 3 down vote to my question . lol.   yes, I know it should go to exit the loop and go to next line. but it didn't.  it print income string just once but didn't close the socket.  that's why I ask the question.

Comment: it should execute the statements if it has exited the loop. Are you sure it has exited the loop ? Or are there any exceptions ?

Comment: Perhaps the server never sent null...perhaps you need a different/additional terminating condition.

Comment: thanks guys,
I'm sure it didn't exit the loop, since if it exit, the socket will close and I will see an socket close message at server site. But if you look at the code, the first time in the loop, it will print out the string in 'in'  and 'in' will be null, and run the loop again. then, 'in' is null and the loop should end. But it didn't. that's the problem that I want to find the reason why.

Comment: are you confusing the `String "null"` with the reserved word `null`?  The two are not the same, which is why I suggested different/additional terminating conditions...